# Is my answer to a propositional calculus book problem syntactically and qualitatively correct?

Tags: logic, set-theory, propositional-calculus

I am trying to solve the following problem in Ted Sundstrom's *Mathematical Reasoning, Writing and Proof*:

> What is the truth set of the sentence $(\exists t \in \mathbb{R})(t \cdot x=20) $?

Earlier in the book the following definition is provided:

> The truth set of an open sentence with one variable is the collection of objects in the universal set that can be substituted for the variable to make the predicate a truth statement

The variable $t$ is not really a variable. It is already quantified by the existential quantifier and so gets substituted into the predicate "by definition". This is not the case for the variable $x$ and for the sentence to become a statement it must take on a value.

If I had to define the truth set for $x$, I'd probably write something like the following:

$$x \in \left\{ \frac {20} {t} \mid t \in \mathbb R \right\}$$

What do you think? Is this the correct answer? How about the notation? Am I getting it right?

Comment: In your statement $t$ is a bounded variable and $x$ is free They are both variables. Your statement is not a sentence because $x$ is free. Sentences have no free variables.

Comment: The author would argue the opposite, namely that this is an open sentence and not a statement. The author defines statements as sentences that can either be true or false.  Open sentences have a subset of the universal set called the truth set for which they evaluate to true.

Comment: You may want to consult other books. The terminology I use is pretty standard.

Comment: Um... I'm going to go with the terminology of the book. Thanks.

Comment: @user32882 Then you will have a lot of trouble communicating with people who use the standard terminology.

Comment: @Alex Kruckman I believe that the book uses the correct terminology. Sentences which contain free variables are open sentences. Sentences which do not contain free variables are either called closed sentences or statements. Statements evaluate to either true or false. Open sentences cannot be evaluated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proposed answer calls for division by $0$.

The truth set is just the set of all nonzero real numbers, since for every nonzero $x$ there is a $t$, namely $20/x$, that makes the assertion true.

In set builder notation the truth set is
$$
\left\{ x \ | \ x \ne 0 \right\}
$$
assuming the universe is the set of real numbers,
$$
\left\{ x \ | \ x \in \mathbb{R} \text{ and } x \ne 0 \right\}
$$
if you need to make that explicit.

Comment: how would you express this in set builder notation?

Comment: @user32882  See my edit.